# How long is the shadow of a 6-foot tree planted 15 feet from a 18-foot lamp post?

Tags: geometry, triangles

> A 6-foot spruce tree is planted 15 feet from a lighted streetlight whose lamp is 18 feet above the ground. How long is the shadow of that tree?

[image]

My idea for finding the length of the shadow is to use the Pythagorean theorem. Is this the right  way to go?

Comment: no,you do not have to. $\frac{x}{6} = \frac{x+15}{18}$

Comment: How did you come up with that answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you don't need the Pythagorean Theorem: You use the fact that for similar triangles, the lengths of respective sides form ratios:

Let $x$ be the unknown length of the shadow:

Then we have an equality of ratios given by $\dfrac{x}{6} = \dfrac{x+15}{18}\tag{1}$

First, we can multiply both sides of $(1)$ by 6, to clear or reduce denominators:

$$6\cdot \dfrac{x}{6} = 6\cdot\dfrac{x+15}{18} \quad\iff\quad x = \frac{x+15}{3}$$

Now we solve for $x$ by cross multiplying: $$3x = x + 15 $$ $$\iff \quad 2x = 15$$

$$\iff x = \frac{15}{2} = \;\;?$$

Comment: Does the question mark equal 7.5?

Comment: Yes, indeed!...

Comment: In the beginning which formula were you using?

Comment: Its the fact that the (**length** of the tree's shadow), divided by the (**height** of the tree), is the equal to (the **length** of the base of the large containing triangle (x + 15)), divided by (the **height** of the light-pole.) Put differently, the ratios of length to height in each case are equal.

Comment: Thanks I understand clearly.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: +1. You are entering to 30k and more spaces. Glad to have you here.

Answer (score 1):

No, you use similar triangles. The tree is one-third the height of the lamp, so the tree’s shadow is one-third of ... what?

Comment: it is one-third of the base.

Comment: @LittleJon: That’s right. And you know how long the other two-thirds of the base is, so ...